# 502 bad gateway using Kubernetes with Ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have a Kubernetes setup on Minikube with this configuration:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myappdeployment
spec:
  replicas: 5
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myapp
          image: custom-docker-image:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000

---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: example-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: myapp
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      # Port accessible inside cluster
      port: 3000
      # Port to forward to inside the pod
      targetPort: 3000
  type: NodePort

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: example-service
          servicePort: 3000
```

I took a look at the solution to [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54783778/502-bad-gateway-with-kubernetes-ingress) and it seems my configuration is.. fine?

What am I doing wrong to get 502 Bad Gateway when accessing http://192.xxx.xx.x, my Minikube address? The `nginx-ingress-controller` logs say:

```
...
Connection refused while connecting to upstream
...
```

Another odd piece of info, when I follow [this guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/) to setting up the basic node service on Kubernetes, everything works and I see a "Hello world" page when I open up the Minikube add

Comment: Is your app definitely listening on port 3000? If you use `kubectl port-forward` to the pod, are you able to `curl` it ok?

Comment: ah interesting, I ran this and it seems I get `an error occurred forwarding 3000 -> 3000` - I looked at the logs for that individual pod and it seems I'm missing the MySQL setup, which stops the pod from starting, despite it being green in the Kubernetes dashboard

Comment: thank you for this! learned a new trick to debug by port-forwarding just one single pod

Comment: Nice, glad to help!

Comment: Please, consider posting an answer if the problem is solved. It would be more clear and helpful for the rest of the community.

Comment: ok I will do that when I get home!

Answer (score 2):

Steps taken:
I ran

```
kubectl port-forward pods/myappdeployment-5dff57cfb4-6c6bd 3000:3000
```

Then I visited `localhost:3000` and saw

```
This page isn’t working
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

I figured the reason is more obvious in the logs so I ran

```
kubectl logs pods/myappdeployment-5dff57cfb4-6c6bd
```

and got

```
Waiting for MySQL...
no destination
Waiting for MySQL...
no destination
Waiting for MySQL...
no destination
Waiting for MySQL...
no destination
...
```

Thus I reasoned that I was originally getting a 502 because all of the pods were not running due to no MySQL setup.